# Rod Cutting Problem (Confusion about price and revenue)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, c++11, greedy

If you are familiar with the rod cutting algorithm, the question is at the bottom.

In the following algorithm (C++ code), rev is the array containing the maximum revenue a rod of given length could have, while the price array is for the standard price without cutting the rod into further pieces. The algorithm given below is what I am finding from many sources to find the maximum revenue of a rod of length n.

```
    int cutRod(int price[], int n) 
    { 
       int rev[n+1]; 
       rev[0] = 0; 
       int i, j; 
       for (i = 1; i<=n; i++) 
       { 
           int max_val = INT_MIN; 
           for (j = 0; j < i; j++) 
              max_val = max(max_val, price[j] + rev[i-j-1]); 
           val[i] = max_val; 
       } 
       return val[n]; 
    }
```

As can be seen, this algorithm works by cutting the rod into two pieces where one piece is not cut further (we consider its price) while the other piece may be cut (we consider its revenue). This means we would need to do this for n times considering different lengths to cut.

QUESTION: Why can't we have this loop run half the number of iterations by passing only revenue of both the pieces rather than one price and one revenue, because revenue holds the information about whether the price is maximum if the rod is cut or if it is not cut? Wouldn't that be more efficient?
Simply put:

    `price[1]<=rev[1], price[2]<=rev[2], ...`

So for rod of length n=3, instead of finding the maximum out of:

    `price[1]+rev[2], price[2]+rev[1], price[3]+rev[0] (n elements)`

we could just find the maximum of:

    `rev[1]+rev[2],rev[3]+rev[0] (⌊n/2⌋ + 1 elements)`

Comment: did you try your idea to see if you get correct results?

Comment: You're doing `for (i = 1; i<=n; i++)`, which, if `n` is the length/size of `price`, means that you're skipping the first element and going one _beyond_ the end of the array. Did you mean `for (i = 0; i<n; i++)` instead? Or, if you _want_ to skip the first element: `for (i = 1; i<n; i++)`?

Comment: @CraigEstey: It can be done either way to consider the option that the rod was not cut (that is, it is cut at length 0 or at length n)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement this by copying prices to the revenue array (takes `O(n)`) and then only looking at the revenue of splits into size `i+j` where `i<j`.  And should get a factor of 2 speed increase.

But it also makes the logic more complicated, which gets in the way of using this as a simple demonstration problem for dynamic programming.  The point isn't to find the factor of 2 algorithmic improvement, but instead to improve the big-`O`.

Secondly the problem has many variants.  In the one you were looking at, there is a price for every length of rod.  But what if you have prices for some lengths but not others?  (For example the USA sells nails in lengths specified in 1/4" increments, but as https://www.homedepot.com/c/ab/types-of-nails/9ba683603be9fa5395fab909c451e98 shows, we only sell some lengths of nail.)  The simpler problem generalizes better.

Comment: Can't understand the last paragraph with the second point. If all lengths were not available, the price+revenue solution will not consider such lengths. The revenue+revenue solution can also work that way, right? Thing is, I can only find the price+revenue solution in college syllabus and websites. I think I am missing something here.

Comment: @N.Paramahamsan The revenue+revenue solution can't ignore such missing lengths because you can achieve them through selling combinations of shorter lengths.  So price+revenue is faster for that variation.  Still the reason you only find price+revenue is mostly due to the second paragraph.  This is an example to demonstrate dynamic programming.  Optimizing it further gets in the way of pedagogy.